# How to divide to rows using flex - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I start to learn html,
I want to create a screen that will have 3 rows in the forth line.
I understood that it could be using flex,
this is my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStayle.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contaner">
        <div class = "header">   
                <div style="display: inline-block;" class="row-1">LOGO</div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;"  class="row-1">Menu</div>

        </div>
        <div class="main">
                <div  class="row-2">picture</div>

                <div style="display: inline-block;" class="row-3">text1</div>
                <div style="display: inline-block;" class="row-3">text2</div>

                <div   class="row-4">pic</div>
                <div   class="row-4">link</div>
                <div   class="row-4">text</div>
        </div>
      

    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

this is my CSS

```
.row-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid black;
    max-width: 100px;
  }

  .row-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid black;
    max-width: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .row-3 {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid black;
    max-width: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .row-4 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex:1 1 30%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 10px solid black;
    max-width: 100px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
```

this is my screen
[image]

and this is what I want to create
[image]

I do not know how to divide the 4 line to three rows. (pic + link + text in the same line)

Comment: You need a 12 column grid and CSS-Grid would work best here.

Comment: add min height for flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to flexbox is proper sectioning of items into containers. In the sample pic you have provided we have one big `container`, which you can further section into `header` and `main`. The header and main are in column layout. `main` further consists of four containers (column layout), each of which contains more items (row layout).

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-2 {
  display: flex;
}

.row-3 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStayle.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div>LOGO</div>
      <div>Menu</div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="row-1">picture</div>
      <div class="row-2">
        <div>text1</div>
        <div>text2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-3">
        <div>pic</div>
        <div>link</div>
        <div>text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-4">
        <div>footer</div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply the HTML as below:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.flex-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
.flex-row div {
    flex: 1;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.flex-row .flex-child-b3 {
    flex: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header flex-row">
        <div class="flex-child-b3">LOGO</div>
        <div>Menu</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div>picture</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div>text1</div>
        <div>text2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <div>pic</div>
        <div>link</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are confusing a flex-container with a flex-item.
Each of your rows should be a flex-container and its elements inside flex-items.
The right way to do this should be:

```
<div class="row-4">
  <div>link</div>
  <div>pic</div>
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

And then to have equally sized columns you will have to set the flex-grow property of every child to "1", or you can also use the shorthand "flex:1".

So your CSS in its very basic form it should look like this:

```
.row-4 {
  display:flex
}

.row-4 > * {
  flex-1:
  text-align:center
}
```

The **text-align** property is what I'm using here to center your text and your images inside each column. Although there are many ways to do this, I find this the easiest one.

Comment: this not worked for me still the 4 row not in the same line